# Calculating time difference in mySQL with a condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this query which must select **1 row**, where `status` is "OKQ", "PI", "CBK", "NRP", "NEW", and if "OKQ", (`status_time` + 86400) must be **SMALLER** than **NOW** which is the current timestamp, so that in the time of execution of the query, status must have `status_time` + 86400 seconds that is already in the **past**, and so on as described in the query:

```
SELECT id FROM leads t JOIN (
    SELECT "OKQ" as status, 86400 as diff UNION ALL
    SELECT "PI" as status, 3600 as diff UNION ALL
    SELECT "CBK" as status, 60 as diff UNION ALL
    SELECT "NRP" as status, 3600 as diff UNION ALL
    SELECT "NEW" as status, 1 as diff
) s USING (status)
WHERE t.status_time > date_sub(now(), interval s.diff second)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1
```

Now this query returns `0` as `num_rows` despite it has most of the records as "NEW", and `status_time` for "NEW" is 4 days old, so `NOW` (current timestamp) is far greater than 4 days ago + 1 second, So one row must be selected.

Comment: I think you might want `<` rather than `>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should look like below, you should use < instead of >

SELECT id FROM leads t JOIN (
    SELECT "OKQ" as status, 86400 as diff UNION ALL
    SELECT "PI" as status, 3600 as diff UNION ALL
    SELECT "CBK" as status, 60 as diff UNION ALL
    SELECT "NRP" as status, 3600 as diff UNION ALL
    SELECT "NEW" as status, 1 as diff
) s USING (status)
WHERE t.status_time < date_sub(now(), interval s.diff second)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 1